# error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type typedef typename _Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;

Tags: c++

I am trying this code about Kohonen Network:

```
// Fausett.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

double euclidean(double *vec1,double *vec2,int n)
{
  double dist = 0.0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) dist += (vec1[i]-vec2[i])*(vec1[i]-vec2[i]);
  return dist;
}

double distance(int i,int jstar)
{
  return double(i!=jstar);
  // returns 1.0 if i!=jstar, returns 0.0 if i==jstar
}

double h(double d) { return 1.0-d; }

void train(double **W,int n,int cols,double *vec,double rate)
{
  int i,j;
  int win = 0;
  double windist = euclidean(W[0],vec,n),edist;
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++){ 
  if((edist=euclidean(W[i],vec,n)) < windist) 
  { win = i; windist = edist;}
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    W[i][j] += (rate*h(distance(i,win)))*(vec[j]-W[i][j]);
}

int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  int T = 10000;     // number of iterations
  double eta = 0.6;  // learning rate
  const int m = 4;
  int cols; 

  // training vectors
  double x0[m] = { 1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0 };
  double x1[m] = { 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };
  double x2[m] = { 1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 };
  double x3[m] = { 0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0 };
  cout << "Enter number of columns for weight matrix: ";  
  cin >> cols;

  double** W = NULL; W = new double*[cols];
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++) W[i] = new double[m];

  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
   for(j=0;j<m;j++) W[i][j] = rand()/double(RAND_MAX);

  for(i=0;i<T;i++)
  {
  train(W,m,cols,x0,eta); train(W,m,cols,x1,eta); 
  train(W,m,cols,x2,eta); train(W,m,cols,x3,eta);
  eta /= 1.05;     // learning rate decreased
  }
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
  {
  cout << "W[" << i << "]= [";
  for(j=0;j<m;j++)  cout << W[i][j] << " ";
  cout << "]" << endl;
  }
  for(i=0;i<cols;i++) delete[] W[i];
  delete[] W;
  return 0;
}
```

its from book Willi - Hans Steeb, I copy paste that, but it gives me error when compiled. error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type typedef typename _Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category, this is one of the error messages and I have no idea at all why this happen. Can someone please explain it? I am a newbie in C++.

Comment: There is a close-brace missing from the end of the program. Once I fix that, [everything compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zP3aPx8s1). (I probably put the close-brace in the wrong place, but at least I got it to compile.)

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove almost all of hat code and still produce the problem.

Comment: This problem could be related to the improper indention of your code. What I mean is if you had good indentation you may have spotted the issue.